# How to convert a 1 channel image into a 3 channel with opencv2?

Tags: python, arrays, opencv

I'm really stumped on this one. I have an image that was *[BGR2GRAY]'d* earlier in my code, and now I need to add colored circles and such to it. Of course this can't be done in a 1 channel matrix, and I can't seem to turn the damned thing back into 3.

`numpy.dstack()` crashes everything

GRAY2BGR does not exist in opencv2

`cv.merge(src1, src2, src3, dst)` has been turned into `cv2.merge(mv)` where mv = "a vector of matrices", whatever that means.

Any ideas?

[Opencv2.4.3 refmanual](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffossies.org%2Funix%2Fmisc%2FOpenCV-2.4.3.tar.gz%3Aa%2FOpenCV-2.4.3%2Fdoc%2Fopencv2refman.pdf&ei=awUWUfnbJ4Ly0wGmuoC4Cw&usg=AFQjCNHZZKb8aioAVevF3gpQQeuRT7SxyQhttps://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffossies.org%2Funix%2Fmisc%2FOpenCV-2.4.3.tar.gz%3Aa%2FOpenCV-2.4.3%2Fdoc%2Fopencv2refman.pdf&ei=awUWUfnbJ4Ly0wGmuoC4Cw&usg=AFQjCNHZZKb8aioAVevF3gpQQeuRT7SxyQ)

Comment: dst  = cv2.merge([src1, src2, src3])

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's a way of doing that in Python:

```
img = cv2.imread("D:\\img.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)

img2 = np.zeros_like(img)
img2[:,:,0] = gray
img2[:,:,1] = gray
img2[:,:,2] = gray

cv2.circle(img2, (10,10), 5, (255,255,0))
cv2.imshow("colour again", img2)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Here's the complete code for OpenCV3:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('10524.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img2 = np.zeros_like(img)
img2[:,:,0] = gray
img2[:,:,1] = gray
img2[:,:,2] = gray
cv2.imwrite('10524.jpg', img2)
```

Answer (score 27):

It is the python equivalent:
    imgray is a numpy array containing 1-channel image.

```
img2 = cv2.merge((imgray,imgray,imgray))
```

Comment: It would be nice if you can explain a bit how your suggested code works. Thanks.

Comment: @sanastasiadis It [merges](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/df2/tutorial_py_basic_ops.html) single-channel images into one three-channel image.

Answer (score 6):

Below I assume you don't have 3-channel image in proper shape, so zeros_like function (used in answer above) will not be useful.

```
img2 = np.zeros( ( np.array(img).shape[0], np.array(img).shape[1], 3 ) )
img2[:,:,0] = img # same value in each channel
img2[:,:,1] = img
img2[:,:,2] = img
```

if img is numpy array then it can be shorten from `np.array(img).shape` to `img.shape`

Answer (score 2):

I was using tensorflow when I needed this. Here's my solution:

```
image = tf.expand_dims(image, -1)
x1 = image.shape[0]
x2 = image.shape[1]
image = tf.reshape(tf.broadcast_to(image, (x1, x2, 3)),  (x1, x2, 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant say about python but I can tell you the C++ interface...

```
gray_image //you have it already
Mat im_coloured = Mat::zeros(gray_image.rows,gray_image.cols,CV_8UC3);

vector<Mat> planes;

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    planes.push_back(gray_image);

merge(planes,im_coloured);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is everybody using `cv2.merge` and low level array operations? Why not simply `use cv2.cvtColor`?

```py
img = np.zeros((640, 480), np.uint8)  # create grayscale image
print(img.shape)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)  # grayscale --> BGR
print(img.shape)
```

which outputs:

```bash
(640, 480)
(640, 480, 3)
```

Comment: I don't know why you use RGB order but okay. OP says "GRAY2BGR does not exist in opencv2" which either has always been wrong, or used to be right, a decade ago, and eventually stopped being right. probably just OP getting misled by bad documentation (back then).

Comment: Sure, let's change it to BGR to follow the cv2 standard channel order. But it actually doesn't matter as cvtColor just triplicate the single channel image for this specific color conversion case. COLOR_GRAY2BGR and COLOR_GRAY2RGB gives the exact same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
RGB = np.stack([gray, gray, gray], axis = -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

if use opencv-python, can use np.repeat function.

```
img = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 2]])
img2 = np.repeat(img[:, :, np.newaxis], 3, axis=2)
```